# onclick to clear form fields JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

I hope this question isn't duplicating something in the archives; I've looked but can't find an answer that solves my problem because I seem to be following the advice given.

I am making a dynamic form with JavaScript and would like to clear the prompts in each field when a user clicks in it.  Here is part of what I have for one of the form fields.  I can't figure out why onlick="this.value=' '";  isn't working.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    var VMake1 = document.createElement("input"); 
    VMake1.name = "veh_1_make"; 
    VMake1.type = "text";
    VMake1.value= "Please enter the make of vehicle 1";
    if (VMake1.value=="Please enter the make of vehicle 1") {   
        onclick="this.value=''";    }   
    placeVeh1Make.parentNode.insertBefore(VMake1,placeVeh1Make);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: don't use `onclick`. Use `addEventListener`.

Comment: The default value should be a default *value*, not a substitute for a `<label>`.

Comment: Are you binding the onclick event to the DOM element? In your case, you can dynamically attach it to your DOM element reference in JavaScript like VMake1.addEventListener (attachEvent for IE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onclick="this.value=''";
```

replace with

```
VMake.onclick="this.value=''"; // or onfocus
```

or, better yet,

```
VMake.addEventListener("click", function(){this.value=''}); // or "focus"
```

If you are willing to use a framework, this is the jQuery way:

```
$(VMake).click(function(){ //or .focus(...)
  this.value=''
});
```

or even

```
$(VMake).click(function(){
  $(this).val('')
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @Jan Dvorak!  It works just beautifully.  And thank you to the other contributors as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for the onFocus event on the field and set the value of the field to an empty string on that event. This also has the benefit of clearing values from fields if the user tabs through the form input fields.

You also need to reference the `VMake1` element when setting the onfocus.  So it might look like this:

```
var VMake1 = document.createElement("input"); 
VMake1.name = "veh_1_make"; 
VMake1.type = "text";
VMake1.value= "Please enter the make of vehicle 1";
VMake1.onfocus = "if (this.value === "Please enter the make of vehicle 1") {this.value='';}";   
placeVeh1Make.parentNode.insertBefore(VMake1,placeVeh1Make);
```

Note that I moved the conditional into the actual onfocus code.

Comment: Thanks.  @Jav Dvorak, I'm a newbie and don't know how to answer your question.  How do I set the scope of the onclick?  And would that be the same way to set the scope of addEventListener and onFocus?

Comment: thank you.  I've added this line into the code:  VMake1.onfocus = "if (this.value === 'Please enter the make of vehicle 1') {this.value='';}";

Comment: but I'm still not getting any result.  When I click or tab into the field, nothing happens.